# Chart JS: Bar Chart to have min Length as value range is too big

Tags: chart.js

I working with ChartJS Bar chart, encountered that small value were not drawn when the value range is too huge.

example [1000,500000000,40000]

This case the chart will only draw out the 500m, and they rest are hidden.

I want show all instead of limiting my max tick.

Answer (score 0):

Did a deeper reading. there's a property called minBarlengh undter dataset. This did the trick.